# How to paginate results when filtering on left join table column

Tags: mikro-orm

Let's define for example these entities:

```
@Entity()
export class Author {

  @OneToMany(() => Book, book => book.author)
  books = new Collection<Book>(this);
}

@Entity()
export class Book {

  @Property()
  name: string;

  @ManyToOne()
  author: Author;
}
```

```
const authors = await authorRepository.find({ books: {name: 'Test'} }, { 
  limit: 10
});
```

As you can see i want to select all authors that have books with name 'Test', but this will generate the following query:

```
select `e0`.* from `author` as `e0`
left join `book` as `e1` on `e0`.`id` = `e1`.`author_id` 
where `e1`.`name` = 'Test' limit 10
```

The problem is when i have more than 2 authors and each of them has more than 10 books with name 'Test', this query will return only the first author because of the limit clause.

I am not sure if this is a bug in the ORM or it's a expected behavior.

One way to fix that is to select all rows without the limit clause and do the pagination in memory like they are doing in hibernate, but i am not sure how much memory will be used with very large tables and this might block the event loop in NodeJS while processing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fallback to query builder here to apply group by clause:

```js
const qb = await authorRepository.createQueryBuilder('a');
qb.select('a.*').where({ books: { name: 'Test' } }).limit(10).groupBy('a.id');
const authors = await qb.getResult();
```

Will think about how to support this use case directly via EM/repository API.